# Django: Could not load model - NOT NULL constraint failed

Tags: django, django-models, fixtures, django-3.2

how are you all?

We are not able to insert the fixures data into our SQLite3 database.

We are using UUid as our model id.

Using the comand python.exe .\manage.py loaddata start.json

Model

```
class Estadual(models.Model):
    # Fields
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    estado = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    sigla = models.CharField(max_length=2, unique=True)
    valor = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, editable=False)

    # Relationships
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        pass
```

start.json

```
[
  {
    "model": "app.estadual",
    "pk": "59472bb0-7f6e-4026-a900-727b7cdd647f",
    "fields": {
      "estado": "AC",
      "sigla": "AC",
      "valor": 12,
      "user": ["4a695e40-6b3a-49fa-8beb-eed853ce17b0"]
    }
  },{
    "model": "app.estadual",
    "pk": "5b321ca7-e8be-4580-8d36-080c663d5397",
    "fields": {
      "estado": "AL",
      "sigla": "AL",
      "valor": 12,
      "user": ["4a695e40-6b3a-49fa-8beb-eed853ce17b0"]
    }
  }
]
```

Error

> Problem installing fixture 'C:...fixtures\start.json': Could not load
> app.Estadual(pk=59472bb0-7f6e-4026-a900-727b7cdd647f): NOT NULL
> constraint failed: app_estadual.created

Comment: You'll need to populate the datetime fields since loading fixtures will not automatically generate them for you.

Comment: Thks. It`s work.